# MS Word VBA search text with find wildcards

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I need find these matches using "ms word find" with wildcards:

```
{{1,000.00}}
{{-125}} 
{{125-}} 
{{-1’100.00}}  
{{1’100.00-}}
```

What should be the **Selection.Find.Text** for it?

I tried this:

```
[\{]{2}<*>[\}]{2}
```

but it does not work for some words.

---

This wildcard works almost exactly to what I need. I modified a bit to exclude Paragraph return ^13 **`[\{]{2}[!\}][!^13]@[\}]{2}`**

However I have a problem matching a paragraph like this `blabla {{2}} {{-2-}} blabla` in this case it matches the whole paragraph (`{{2}} {{-2-}}`) and then it matches `{{-2-}}`.

Can someone tell me the reason, and what I need to change in the wildcards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` and `>` are the *word-boundary* wildcards.  For them to work, the first and last characters inside the braces would have to be letters or digits (or whatever Word's `Find` considers to be a "word" character).  Try this instead:

```
[\{]{2}[!\}]@[\}]{2}
```

`[!\}]@` should match one or more of any characters except `}`.

Comment: Hi Alan,
Thank you for your help, this wildcards works almost exactly to what I need. I modified a bit to exclude char return **`[\{]{2}[!\}][!^13]@[\}]{2}`**

However the problem for this sentence **`" {{2}}  {{-2-}} "`** for some reasons it matches the whole word and then it matches the last one, any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: You need to merge those two character classes into one: `[!\}^13]@`.  The way you have it, `[!\}]` matches the first character after the opening braces, then `[!^13]@` gobbles up everything else.  Unless it encounters a carriage return, that is.  And speaking if that, if you don't want to match carriage returns, shouldn't you reject linefeeds as well?  `[!\}^10^13]@`

Comment: Hi Alan,
Thanks again for your help, doing what you suggested worked like charm, however adding `^10` doesn't match anything at all.
I am now using this `[\{]{2}[!\}^13]@[\}]{2}` the only tiny problem now is that it does not match this one `{{}}` (if empty), anything else works fine.

Comment: Apparently, `@` means **one** or more, not *zero* or more like it does in Visual Studio regexes.  There doesn't seem to be a single-character zero-or-more wildcard, either, so it looks like you'll have to use `{0,}`

Comment: I tried `[\{]{2}[!\}^13]{0,}[\}]{2}`, but it does not work, did I miss something or wrong order?

Comment: I tried `[\{]{2}[!\}^13]{0,}[\}]{2}`, but it does not work, did I miss something or wrong order?
I tried also `[\{]{2}[!\}^13]*[\}]{2}` and for `{{}}` still not luck.

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas. :-/  You might have better luck if you ask this question on [su].  It seems more like a Word question than a regex question.

Comment: Solved by searching first with [\{]{2}[!\}^13]@[\}]{2} and finally
[\{]{2}[\}]{2} and that solved my problem.
thanks for the help.