# Finding String based on Starting/Ending Chars with variable inner chars in Word Doc & Replacing

Tags: excel, ms-word, find, vba

I currently am using Excel to search whole word documents for a identifiable string based on the starting and ending characters. The middle characters will be differing. The starting chars will always be << and the ending ones will always be >>.  Example << Text to Delete >>. I am trying to locate all instances of this and delete them including the <<>> characters. Below is my current code, which works to delete straight text, but when I try to add a asterisk to designate anything between << and >>, it no longer works.

I believe that it isn't recognizing the * as 'anything', but I do not know how to update to allow that. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub AddRemoveWatermark(blWatermarkAction As Boolean, blDeleteText As Boolean, strInitialIdentifier As String, strEndingIdentifier As String)
    'Word Variables
    Dim wrdApplication As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDocument As Word.Document
    Dim wrdSection As Word.section
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim lngCount As Long

    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

        Set wrdApplication = New Word.Application

        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            Set wrdDocument = wrdApplication.Documents.Open(strPath)

            wrdApplication.Visible = True

            'Delete all starting << and ending >>
            With wrdDocument.Range.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = strInitialIdentifier & "*" & strEndingIdentifier
                .Forward = True
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                '.MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
            End With
        Next lngCount
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question should be marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7408485/6535336)

Comment: If I read that other question / answer correctly, it sounds like you might want a string of `[\<]{2}[!\>]@[\>]{2}`.

Comment: I tried that as a string and it does not match or find anything. I read and interpreted the post you referenced and it seems you would be correct per their logic, but it is not returning any example with the .Text being "[\<]{2}[!\>]@[\>]{2}"

Comment: I also wonder if I need to use .MatchWildcards = True.    I tried it, and get run time error 5560 which advises "contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid"   Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tested (using Word VBA, not Word invoked from Excel, but I doubt if that would affect the Find operation) your `With wrdDocument.Range.Find` block with two modifications, i.e. `.Text = "[\<]{2}[!\>]@[\>]{2}"` and uncommenting `.MatchWildcards = True`, and it successfully changed my test text of `Sdaf saf <<daghas>> fdsdfsd` to `Sdaf saf  fdsdfsd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code was successfully run from an Excel workbook:

```
Sub AddRemoveWatermark(blWatermarkAction As Boolean, blDeleteText As Boolean, strInitialIdentifier As String, strEndingIdentifier As String)
    'Word Variables
    Dim wrdApplication As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDocument As Word.Document
    Dim wrdSection As Word.section
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim lngCount As Long

    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

        Set wrdApplication = New Word.Application

        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            Set wrdDocument = wrdApplication.Documents.Open(strPath)

            wrdApplication.Visible = True

            'Delete all starting << and ending >>
            With wrdDocument.Range.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "[\<]{2}[!\>]@[\>]{2}"
                .Forward = True
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
            End With
        Next lngCount
    End With
End Sub
```

From the `FileDialog` I selected a Word document which contained a single paragraph saying `Sdaf saf <<agfjgadf>> fdsdfsd` and it changed the string to be `Sdaf saf  fdsdfsd`.

Note:  The code as it is currently written leaves the edited documents open, and unsaved.  I'm not sure whether that is intended or not.

Comment: I am glad you are persistent @YowE3K as I must have messed something up after I posted the question as you are correct. I have reset it back to that and it worked great. Per your other comment, I did remove the end code to close and save to simplify the posting, but you are correct that I am doing that in my implementation.  Thank you!!!